# Adjust parent DIV height to inner content (RSS feeds)

Tags: jquery, html, css, rss

I'm embedding a RSS feed into my html site using the Google Feed API.
I tried to make the parent-DIV adjust its height with jquery:

```
function setHeightParent() {
                $("#Parent").height($("#feed").height() + 200);
                }
```

This results in a parent-DIV with a height of 200 px.
I think the height is calculated before the "feed" div has any content therefore no height..
What am I doing wrong, how can I make it take the height of the final "feed" div?

Answer (score 1):

I got it...

Amir was kinda right about the delay.

Solved it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function setHeightParent() {
        $("#Parent").css("height", $("#feed").height() + 250);
    }
setTimeout(setHeightParent, 800)
});
```